# Validator regex pattern input accept only a number with 2-5 digits

Tags: regex, validation, jsf

I want to validate user's input data with a custom Validator in a JSF application. The data inserted must be a number between 2 and 5 digits.

Facelet

```
<h:inputText id="num1" label="num1" required="true" size="5" maxlength="5" 
styleClass="#{component.valid ? '' : 'validation-failed'}"
value="#{sumaManagedBean.number1}"
requiredMessage="You must enter a value">
<f:validator validatorId="validators.NumberValidator"/>    
</h:inputText>
<h:message for="num1" />
```

ManagedBean

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SumaManagedBean implements Serializable
{

    int number1;

    public SumaManagedBean() {
    }

    //Getters and Setters
    public int getNumber1() {
        return number1;
    }

    public void setNumber1(int number1) {
        this.number1 = number1;
    }

    //Methods
}
```

Validator

```
@FacesValidator("validators.NumberValidator")
public class NumberValidator implements Validator
{
    private static final String NUMBER_PATTERN = "[0-9]{1,5}";

    private Pattern pattern;
    private Matcher matcher;

    public NumberValidator()
    {
        pattern = Pattern.compile(NUMBER_PATTERN);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,Object value) throws ValidatorException 
    {
        String number = value.toString();

        //Only numeric characters
        matcher = pattern.matcher(value.toString());
        if(!matcher.matches())
        {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Only numeric characters");
            msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            throw new ValidatorException(msg);

        } 
        //Minimum length 2 numbers
        else if((number.length() < 2))  
        {  
            FacesMessage msg =  new FacesMessage("Minimum length 2 numbers");
            msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            throw new ValidatorException(msg);
        }  
    }     
}
```

When I insert a one digit number, the validator works properly and shows the message "Minimum length 2 numbers". But when I insert some letters instead of numbers like "eee3", the validator shows the following message: "num1: 'eee3' must be a number between -2147483648 and 2147483647. Example: 9346", when it should show "Only numeric characters".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just cast the input as number and verify if its >99 and <=99999?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *But when I insert some letters instead of numbers like "eee3", the validator shows the following message: "num1: 'eee3' must be a number between -2147483648 and 2147483647. Example: 9346"*

That's the default conversion error message of JSF builtin [`IntegerConverter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/convert/IntegerConverter.html). It will transparently kick in when you bind an input field to a bean property of type `Integer` or its primitive counterpart `int`. JSF converters will run before JSF validators. On any conversion error, the validators won't run. In other words, you don't need to validate against that numeric regex pattern at all.

You can customize that converter message via `converterMessage` attribute.

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.integer}" ... converterMessage="Only numeric characters" />
```

Moreover, that length (range) validation can also be done by JSF builtin [`<f:validateLongRange>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/f/validateLongRange.html).

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.integer}">
    <f:validateLongRange minimum="10" maximum="99999" />
</h:inputText>
```

Its validator message can be customized via `validatorMessage` attribute. All in all, your input component can with essential parts look just like this, without any custom validator:

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.integer}" maxlength="5" required="true"
    requiredMessage="You must enter a value"
    converterMessage="Only numeric characters"
    validatorMessage="Minimum length 2 numbers">
    <f:validateLongRange minimum="10" maximum="99999" />
</h:inputText>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, doing a `value.toString()` inside a `Validator` is bad practice. Don't do that. You're supposed to cast the provided value argument to the actual type as declared in the model (the bean property). You'd then quickly have realized that some parts of your validation was unnecessary.

```
Integer number = (Integer) value;
```

And, a `Matcher` instance is [not thread safe](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html). You're not supposed to declare it as an instance variable of a class whose instances could be shared across multiple threads.

Comment: How can one know something is thread unsafe though it is explicitly stated in this case, "*Instances of this class are not safe for use by multiple concurrent threads.*"?

Comment: @Tiny: `Matcher` is stateful and not synchronized. I.e. it has instance variables which can be manipulated by unsynchronized instance methods.